# Exploiting the CSS system in a database

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, pdo

I am creating a page which must save some CSS attributes into a MySQL database, however it has occurred to me that if someone edits the CSS (via chrome dev tools for example), they may be able to insert "bad" values into the database for example:

```
background-color: EXPL0IT;
```

However when attempting such stuff via the dev tools, it *never* enters this bad text into the database, and only uses the "correct" values - even for background colours.

So my question is, is there a way that someone can exploit the developer tools (on any browser) in such a way to insert bad CSS values into the database?

EDIT:

Sample code for inserting the background values:

```
if ($update = $db->prepare("UPDATE user_pages SET `background-color` = :color, `background-size` = :size, `background-position` = :position, `background-repeat` = :repeat, `background-attachment` = :attachment, `background-image` = :image WHERE hash = :hash AND user_id = :id LIMIT 1"))
{
    $update->bindValue(":color", $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":size", $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":position", $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":repeat", $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":attachment", $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":image", $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":hash", $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindValue(":id", $cUser->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I am currently using jQuery and AJAX to complete this PDO MySQLi statement.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking... A CSS edited on the client site via any means (console or otherwise) is never sent back to the server and thus cannot update your database. You might want to add more information.

Comment: @Blizz When the user clicks a "Save" button it sends my CSS data for the background to the database to be saved. So I am wondering if there is any way that the user can modify the CSS through web-tools which will insert these modified values into the database.

For example: someone could edit the background color through chrome dev-tools to be set as "EXPLOIT" which would be invalid; and if they did this, would that BAD value be inserted into the database when the user clicks "SAVE" afterwards?

Comment: Yes you keep repeating yourself and not adding more information... What is the normal way a user would enter these values? What does save do exactly? Update the question.

Comment: As Blizz noted, when you input stuff in the dev tools (HTML, CSS even javascript), those values cannot be sent to your server (you can change css color, but when you refresh the site the changes would be gone). Unless you have some kind of plugin that will save those values in the input field on your site and then those values would get sent to your server.

Comment: I am making the CSS values be entered into the database through the use of jQuery and AJAX. In normal use, a user can select a color from a list and it generates the css color to insert into the database such as : var col = $("something").css("background-color") <-- this value is to be inserted into the database. But if someone were to use the developer tools to modify this value and then click save, would it use the value entered from the developer tools or from the color when the user clicked it?